# How to check if Drupal user is logged in via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a specific cookie Drupal uses to determine if a user is logged in or anonymous?

I need to check the cookie, and create a rewrite condition based on whether or not the user is logged in.

In the end, I would like something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !drupaluser=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?no-cookies-for-you=%1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what that rewrite condition should be doing?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - edited the question

Comment: ok, that's a partial answer/clarification for my prior comment, merci! From your question I already understand that you want something to happen (or maybe not happen) if a user is yes or no logged in. But can you elaborate a bit please to explain (in English or Drupaleze) **what** should happen (or not), depending on yes or no logged in?

Comment: If user is logged in i would like to set a cookie, if not i would like to redirect to a specific page

Comment: OK, that's clear. But what about an authenticated user who has disabled cookies (what should happen in that case then)? Would it be an option for you to consider a custom field added to the user profile (updated automatically with whatever info you want to store in your cookie ... which would also work if cookies are disabled)?

Comment: No. Not worried about if cookies are disabled.

Comment: Hm, bizarre ... so would a solution where you never set a cookie (for any logged in user) be acceptable also then? In that case it would be a piece of cake ...

Answer (score 2):

Drupal does store the session value in the cookie variable after the user is logged in. However, the name of this cookie is not fixed. It is basically a string that comes from the value returned by PHP function [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php); and starts with `SESS`. It would be hard to find and I would not recommend using regex, as I personally don't like it much.

If you really want to implement a solution with the cookie, I would suggest the following:

1. Implement [hook_user_login()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7.x) in a custom module:

   ```
   function MODULE_user_login() {
     // set a new cookie here, with static name and value.
   }
   ```
2. Implement [hook_user_logout()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/7.x) and delete the cookie by setting an expiry date of past.

You can now use this cookie in your .htaccess!

Comment: I agree with your recommendation about what NOT to do (as in your first parg). And I bet you can guess how I might answer this question (after I know the answer to my 2nd comment below the question) ... Though your answer here, via a custom module, also makes a lot of sense of course (for those who like writing, maintaining and (later on) upgrading custom modules).